# SQL query how to extract number of records opened per day, week, month

Tags: sql, db2

I have table `ticket` in DB2 with this information on example

```
TICKETID  CREATIONDATE
1000         2012-05-01 11:11:11
1001         2012-05-01 12:11:11
1002         2012-05-05 11:11:11
1003         2012-05-12 11:11:11
1004         2012-05-19 11:11:11
1005         2012-05-27 11:11:11
1006         2012-06-01 11:11:11
1007         2012-06-03 11:11:11
```

So I would like something like this in output

```
DATE           NUMBER
2012-05-01       2
2012-05-05       1
2012-05-12       1
2012-05-19       1
2012-05-27       1
2012-06-01       1
2012-06-01       1
```

For Month:

```
MONTH  NUMBER
May      6
June     2
```

And for weeks I don't know what is the most feasible and visually the best way to present?

Comment: When you list 'month', do you care about a particular year, or are you wanting to roll up all years together?  Also for weeks - when does the week start?  Are we talking ISO week numbers (which can mean that week 1 of the year actually starts in December of the previous year), weeks since the _actual_ start of the month, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what platform you're running DB2 on, but if it's on Linux, UNIX or Windows you can look at the `DATE()`, `WEEK()` and `MONTHNAME()` functions.  All three can be applied to the CREATIONDATE column.